# Is there a way to extract a line from the multiple .txt files using cmd?

Tags: cmd

I'd like to extract an n line from multiple .txt files in a folder. Is there a way to do this using cmd?

Comment: sorry, not clear. Is it "show the <n>th line from each file"?

Comment: @Stephan I'd like to have an output .txt file which shows third line of every .txt file in the folder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find /n /v ""` to enumerate the lines, filter for the correct line number with `find "[3]" or - more safe - with` findstr /bl "[3]"`and remove the line numbers with the`for /f` loop. finally redirect the output to a file (preferably outside the processed folder, or it might get processed too):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set linenr=3
(for /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" * ^|findstr /bl "[%linenr%]"') do echo/%%b)>..\out.txt
```